# Register MetricRegistry inside Dropwizard Bundle

Tags: java, bundle, dropwizard, codahale-metrics

I am creating a Dropwizard Bundle to be reused across all my microservices. One of the things I would like to standardize on is the `MetricRegistry` each service uses.

It would be great if I could I could configure each service to use the same `MetricRegistry` by simply adding my bundle on init, so something like:

```
class Microservice1 extends Application<Microservice1Config> {
    @Override
    void initialize(Bootstrap<Microservice1Config> cfg) {
        // Boom! Standardized metrics/reporters configured and initialized!
        bootstrap.addBundle(new MyBundle())
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `Bundle` API doesn't seem to be conducive to this type of behavior:

```
class MyBundle implements Bundle {
    MetricRegistry metricRegistry

    @Override
    void initialize(Bootstrap bootstrap) {

    }

    @Override
    void run(Environment environment) {
        environment.jersey().register(???)
    }
}
```

Since the `register(...)` method doesn't register `metricRegistry` as a JAX-RS resource, I'm at a loss as to how to wire things up so that this `metricRegistry` is used for all metrics throughout the entire microservice. Ideas?

---

#### Update

What I'm looking for is where to put the following:

```
MetricRegistry metricRegistry = new MetricRegistry()
Slf4jReporter slf4jReporter = Slf4jReporter.forRegistry(metricRegistry)
    .convertRatesTo(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .convertDurationsTo(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build()

slf4jReporter.start(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, there is a metric registry accessible from `environment.metrics()`.  There are lots of ways to get that injected where you need it.  I use the [dropwizard-guice](https://github.com/HubSpot/dropwizard-guice) bundle to add Guice support.

```
private GuiceBundle<MyConfiguration> guiceBundle;

@Override
public void initialize(Bootstrap<MyConfiguration> bootstrap) {

  guiceBundle = GuiceBundle.<MyConfiguration>newBuilder()
    .addModule(new MyModule())
    .setConfigClass(MyConfiguration.class)
    .build(Stage.DEVELOPMENT);

  bootstrap.addBundle(guiceBundle);
}
```

Then I create a provider rule in the application's module for the metric registry.

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {

  ...

  @Provides
  @Singleton
  public MetricRegistry provideRegistry( Environment environment ) {
    return environment.metrics();
  }
}
```

And in my resource, I mark the registry as injected.

```
@Path("/resource")
public class MyResource {
  @Inject
  MetricRegistry registry;
}
```

Finally, I am requesting my static resources from Guice's injector and then passing an instance to Jersey, instead of a class name.

```
@Override
public void run(Environment environment) {
  Injector injector = guiceBundle.getInjector();
  environment.jersey().register(injector.getInstance(MyResource.class));
}
```

You could probably just register the class name and rely on the Guice/HK2 bridge to provide the injection, but historically Guice/HK2 integration has been problematic.

Once you have the metric registry wired up, you will need to configure metrics to send data somewhere.  You can do this with the [metrics configuration block](https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/manual/configuration.html#metrics).

For example, if you would like to send metrics to graphite, you can set up the [graphite metrics reporter](http://www.dropwizard.io/manual/configuration.html#graphite-reporter).  You will need to add a dependency on the graphite reporter.

```
<dependency>
  <artifactId>dropwizard-metrics-graphite</artifactId>
  <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
  <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

and add configuration for the reporter.

```
metrics:
  reporters:
    - type: graphite
      prefix: <PREFIX_FOR_METRICS>
      host: <GRAPHITE_HOST>
      port: <GRAPHITE_PORT>
      frequency: 10s
```

Comment: Thanks @C.Trimble (+1 - you're soo close!) - one super-quick followup question for the green check + bounty: *where do I actually configure the `MetricRegistry` and respective metrics reporter?* Thanks again!

Comment: @smeeb does the information I added on configuration help?

Comment: Thanks again @C.Trimble (+1 again) - please see my update. Before `environment.metrics()` can return a value, I need to instantiate the `MetricRegistry` first - but where?!? Thanks again!

Comment: ...Or is it that Dropwizard **creates** `environment.metrics()` for you? If that's the case, then how do you configure it and, say, specify an `Slf4jReporter` on it?

Comment: Dropwizard manages that metrics registry for you.  You just need to attach reporters to it.

Comment: Can I supply my own singleton metric registry to DropWizard or do I need to use the one DropWizard creates?

Comment: It doesn't look like the `Environment` object provides a method for setting the registry.  Why would you want to do that?

Comment: When I do that I get this error. It seems I can't use the environment in the GuiceBundle?

`ERROR [2015-11-12 16:25:05,788] com.hubspot.dropwizard.guice.GuiceBundle: Exception occurred when creating Guice Injector - exiting
! com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:
! 
! 1) The dropwizard environment has not yet been set. This is likely caused by trying to access the dropwizard environment during the bootstrap phase.
!   at com.hubspot.dropwizard.guice.DropwizardEnvironmentModule.providesEnvironment(DropwizardEnvironmentModule.java:36)`

Comment: I realised you can get the metrics registry from the bootstrap object, then pass it in to the bundle's constructor.

Comment: @martincharlesworth I have updated the code to include `guiceBundle = builder.build(Stage.DEVELOPMENT);`.  This is needed to make singletons lazy, so that they initialize after the Environment is injected.  This is a rough spot between the hubspot code and dropwizard.

Comment: @C.Trimble Thanks that works. Your code isn't quite right (you already built the guice bundle once) but I get the point.

Comment: @martincharlesworth I have corrected that error, thanks!